# Correcting output from Bibble 5 Lite

Tags: linux, color-correction, color-management, bibble

Bibble 5 Lite only allows output in `Kodak ProPhoto RGB`, which quite a few applications do not represent correctly (esp. when uploading to web services).

AFAIK, Bibble 5 Lite is hard-coded only to support this color profile, so it's not possible to change there. GIMP supports "correcting" it to sRGB, but is quite heavy to fire up for each picture I output.

So -- is there any way around this? Either a simple application to bulk-change the color profile, or perhaps some solution within Bibble?

(I'm not a color-profile expert, so I might have overlooked something obvious.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://bibblelabs.com/products/bibble5/learn/webhelp/index.html?batch_output.html), *"Bibble 5 Lite offers sRGB and ProPhotoRGB (the working space), while Bibble 5 Pro offers a broad selection of color profiles."* It's under Additional Image Settings in the output settings for the queue.

Comment: FWIW, I just verified this in my own install. It works. Beats me why Kodak ProPhoto RGB is the default (it was sRGB in version 5.0).

Answer (score 0):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) has a batchmode and a huge array of functions. Perhaps it can correct the color  space too.